# The Broccoli Plugin: [BroccoliTypeScriptCompiler] failed with + NgModule + Routing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

[image]

I have generated angular 2 application using Angular CLI. But i have updated the package.json manually acoording to angular/quickstart package.json

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems you are using an old version of angular-cli. Try uninstalling angular-cli globally (npm uninstall -g angular-cli) and reinstall the latest version (at the moment .17, npm install -g angular-cli@latest).
You might have to update the cli-version in your angular-cli.json as well.
The version in your package.json for angular-cli says "any version". That might be a problem as well. Try explicitly setting the current version.

Greetings